# multiple image tags for facebook

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

I try to do include multiple og:image meta properties to associate multiple images with my page. According to Facebook's Open Graph protocol documentation, you have only put multiple og:image tags in the html head.

That's what I did but unfortunately it doesn't work. 
I would be pleased, if anyone could give me a hint.

Code:

```
<head>
  <meta name="og:title" content="Parents Inc." />
  <meta name="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta name="og:image" content="http://theparentingplace.automatem.co.nz//images/stories/media/Our%20Speakers/amanda_headshot.jpg" />
  <meta name="og:image" content="http://theparentingplace.automatem.co.nz//images/stories/media/Our%20Speakers/bruce_headshot.jpg" />
  <meta name="og:image" content="http://theparentingplace.automatem.co.nz//images/stories/media/Our%20Speakers/dave_phoebe_headshot.jpg" />
  ...
  <meta name="og:image" content="http://theparentingplace.automatem.co.nz//images/stories/media/Our%20Speakers/zane_headshot.jpg" />
  ...
```

You can see an example page here:

http://pastehtml.com/view/bl3wbdtiu.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pastehtml.com/view/bl3wbdtiu.html

This has

`<meta name="og:title" content="Parents Inc.">`

which should be changed to

`<meta property="og:title" content="Parents Inc.">`

You should also add `xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"` as a property of your HTML tag too.
`<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">` or like `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`

Further reading can be done:  http://ogp.me/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Cheers DMCS, the name instead of property was the problem

Comment: Easy to overlook!  Glad to help.